# Where can I find Mambo 3 downloads / documentation?

Tags: joomla

Does anyone know where I could find copies of the Mambo 3.0.x distributions, manuals and (ideally) instructions for upgrading to Mambo 4.x or Joomla?

I have an old site implemented in Mambo 3 that needs to be upgraded.  It doesn't work with PHP 5 without hacks that compromise PHP security, and the site admin and navigation menus are broken for "modern" browsers; e.g. IE6 and later.

Comment: (This should be tagged 'mambo', but I don't have the rep points.)

Comment: Mambo tag added

Comment: Have you tried http://mambo-foundation.org? The instructions for upgrading to Mambo 4.x would probably come with Mambo 4.x. Everything should be in their SVN repo. You can get support here: http://mambo-support.org/

Comment: Has your question been answered or do you need more infomration regarding the Mambo 3?

Comment: @Christopher - we abandoned the task as being too much work for too little payoff.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to upgrade from Mambo 3 to Joomla 1.6 is probably not worth the time it would take. You would have to rebuild the template, find different plugins, extensions, etc. You are best off starting with a fresh install of Joomla 1.6 and manually migrating the content over.